# extract number of Repetition n of every string in a string list

Tags: vb.net, linq

All,
I have a data table one of the column
(string type ) is having value like this

[image]

want one more column to be added and it should be like this

[image]

where the right side column indicates how many times the left side value has occurred so far. I want this to be done via LINQ. I have some method already that is very in efficient.

My algorithm :
assume column name here we are dealing with is col1 and the new col waht we want to add is col2

```
for every unique value in the data table  in col1 
     collect the indices on which this value appear
     in data table on column2 for each row of these indices put a value as 1 ,2,3
```

Comment: One word `GroupBy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/group-by-clause

Comment: hi am new to this can you please little elaborate on how todo ?  my group by results will be like abc will be 2 and bcd will be 3 etc., at max i can make a dictionary out of that. 
but what i need is little different. every row must have an occurrence number . say bcd will be having 3 numbers 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Please don't post the data as images. Please post it as valid VB.NET code. Then we can easily post an answer.

Comment: I'm not a VB man. But in C# it will be `items.GroupBy(i => i.Name).Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});`

Comment: the result of this is may be a dict having abc -2 , bcd - 3 etc.,
mypoint is including  the first occurance every string should be associated with the a list of string .. that list for abc is 1,2 for bcd 1,2,3

Comment: or not even a list. as i said its a data table i need one more column thats all. in that we can have these numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, I almost finished my answer when I noticed you want it in VB, not C#!

Ah well, maybe you still understand the methods I use, or some other reader can use it.

Because some LINQ statements you might loose the original order, you could first add the index to the original sequence of Names. Then you make groups of same Name, Order the elements in the Group by Index, then add an "AppearanceCount", unGroup all elements and finally order by Original index.

Not sure if this is efficient:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = ...
var result = names.Select( (name, i) => new
{
    Index = i,
    Name = name,
})
```

So {ABC DEF GH, ...}I => { {0, ABC}, {1, DEF}, {2, GHI}, {3, ...

```
// GroupBy same Name:
.GroupBy(indexedName => indexedName.Name,

    // parameter resultSelector: take every Name and all IndexNames with this name
    // to make one new:
    (name, indexedNamesInThisGroup) => new
    {
        Name = name,
        // from every IndexedName in this Group: OrderBy index, and add a Count:
        Indexes =  indexNamesInThisGroup
            .OrderBy(indexedName => indexName.Index)
            .Select( (indexedName, i) => new
            {
                Index = indexedName.Index,
                Count = i + 1,
            },
    });
```

You have made groups and ordered the elements, then you added a count. Because you start your first count with 1 I need to add +1;

For example:

```
{0, ABC}, {1, DEF}, {2, ABC}, {3, XYZ}, {4, ABC}, {5, XYZ}, {6, ABC}, ... =>

Group ABC has elements {0, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 3} {6, 4}
Group DEF has elements {1, 1}
Group XYZ has elements {3, 1} {5, 2}
```

So from every Group the key has the name of all elements in the group. Every member in the group has the original index number and a count: "this original index number was the first / second / third time that ABC appeared"

Now all you have to do is use SelectMany to ungroup, order by original sequence and remove the original index:

```
.SelectMany(group => group, (key, groupElement) => new
{
    Name = key,
    Index = groupElement.Index,
    Count = groupElement.Count,
})
.OrderBy(ungroupedElement => ungroupedElement.Index)
.Select(ungroupedElement => new
{
    Name = ungroupedElement.Name,
    Count = ungroupedElement.Count,
});
```

This is one horrible LINQ statement. I don't know how many times this will enumerate your original sequence.

I think an extension method like the following will be way more efficient.

```
public static IEnumerable<CountedName> ToCountedNames(this IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> countedNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        // did we see this name before?
        int nameCount;
        if (countedNames.TryGetValue(name, out nameCount)
        {
            // Yes we saw it before, add +1
            nameCount += 1;
            countedNames[name] = nameCount;
        }
        else
        {
            // no we didn't see it before, add this name with a Count 1:
            nameCount = 1;
            countedNames.Add(name, nameCount);
        }


        yield return new CountedName
        {
            Name = name,
            Count = nameCount,
        };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = ...
IEnumerable<CountedName> countedNames = names.ToCountedNames();
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion given by Svyatoslav in the comments does not do exactly what you want, since it uses GroupBy to give total counts whereas you want a running count.  In order to achieve this you need to have some method to order the items in your data.  By way of illustration I show some code below (using a simple VB Console App):

First you need a class like this:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Sub New(pid As Int32, pname As String)
        ID = pid
        Name = pname
    End Sub
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ID As Int32
End Class
```

Now you can use this class within the Main sub thus:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim items As New List(Of Item)({New Item(1, "abc"), New Item(2, "bcd"), New Item(3, "abc"), New Item(4, "pen"), New Item(5, "efh"), New Item(6, "vgn"), New Item(7, "bcd"), New Item(8, "mno"), New Item(9, "tap"), New Item(10, "pen"), New Item(11, "efh"), New Item(12, "bcd")})

    Dim t = From i In items
            Select New With {i.Name, items.Where(Function(x) x.ID <= i.ID AndAlso x.Name = i.Name).Count()}

    For Each t2 In t
        Console.WriteLine(t2.Name + ", " + t2.Count.ToString())
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

By way of explanation.  I am initialising a List of type Item, using your values but with an extra field that I can use for ordering.  I then use LINQ to generate an Anonymous Type containing the Name plus the Count of all occurences of the Name upto and including the current position in the List; this is done by matching the Name, and including all IDs less than or equal to the current ID.

I then iterate through the Anonymous List writing to the Console.  Console.ReadLine is added at the end, to make sure I have a chance to read the values, before the Console window closes!

Assuming your data has some column that you can order on, you should be able to adapt this to suit your purposes.

Comment: that extra number field that you added is what the actual result is . so am not sure how / why u are adding it initially

Comment: No it isn't. If you check my code you will see that the extra field I have added is a unique ID from 1 .. 12.  This is not shown in the output.  Instead it is used to order the items, so that the running count is correct.  If you check my output, you will see that the output has the running totals that you want and not the IDs.  Please read my answer more carefully.